# HDP upgrade to 2.6.4 failed from HDP current version - 2.6.0.3

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper, ambari

we have ambari cluster version - 2.5.0.3 ( with 3 masters nodes and 3 workers nodes )

we are in the middle of upgrade from HDP version 2.6.0.3 to 2.6.4 version

in the final stage installation failed

[image]

the errors that apears under - Finalize Upgrade Pre-Check are

```
The following components were found to have version mismatches.  Finalize will not complete successfully:
master03.sys5dns.com: HDFS/ZKFC reports UNKNOWN
master01.sys5dns.com: HDFS/ZKFC reports UNKNOWN
```

also that:

```
{"hosts":["master01.sys5dns.com","master03.sys5dns.com"],"host_detail":{"master01.sys5dns.com":[{"service":"HDFS","component":"ZKFC","version":"UNKNOWN"}],"master03.sys5dns.com":[{"service":"HDFS","component":"ZKFC","version":"UNKNOWN"}]}}
```

we are stuck in this stage

please advice what is the meaning of - HDFS/ZKFC reports UNKNOWN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have been fixed in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-21526
Looks like ZKFC started advertising a version between HDP-2.3 and HDP-2.4. The suggestion would be to rollback to backup, upgrade Ambari to at least 2.5.2 and then upgrade stack

Or you may try looking up for a less drastic solution at https://community.hortonworks.com/index.html

Comment: thank you I will downgrade and then install the new ambari version and then HDP upgrade , I will let you know the final status , ( +1 for your answer )